# To stop button pass to another page JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Before clicking the button to execute, I want to verify whether the filled content meets the requirements. If there is any error message, the page cannot be redirected.
I used .preventDefault(), but it didn't work. Even error, the page was still redirected.

```js
let btnAjtBtlCellier = document.getElementById('ajouterBouteilleCellier');
let fAjtBtlCellier = document.getElementById('form-ajouter-btl');
let inputEles = document.querySelectorAll('#form-ajouter-btl input');
let erreurAjtBtl = false;
inputEles.forEach(function(element) {
  //Verify all required inputs
  element.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
    quantiteValideAjt();
    date_achatValideAjt();
    prixValideAjt();
  })
});

btnAjtBtlCellier.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  erreurAjtBtl = false;
  if (erreurAjtBtl) evt.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<div class="form-ajouter" id="form-ajouter-btl">
  <p>Nom : <span data-id="" class="nom_bouteille"></span></p>
  <span id="errNom_ajouter"></span>
  <label for="millesime_ajouter">Millesime : </label>
  <input type="text" name="millesime" id="millesime_ajouter" value="2020">
  <label for="quantite_ajouter">Quantite : </label>
  <input type="text" name="quantite" value="1" id="quantite_ajouter">
  <span id="errQuantite_ajouter"></span>
  <label for="date_achat_ajouter">Date achat : </label>
  <input type="date" name="date_achat" id="date_achat_ajouter" value="">
  <span id="errAchat_ajouter"></span>
  <label for="prix_ajouter">Prix : </label>
  <input type="text" name="prix" id="prix_ajouter" value="">
  <span id="errPrix_ajouter"></span>
  <label for="garde_jusqua_ajouter">Garde : </label>
  <input type="text" name="garde_jusqua" id="garde_jusqua_ajouter">
  <label for="notes_ajouter">Notes</label>
  <input type="text" id="notes_ajouter" name="notes">
  <!-- input caché avec id usager -->
  <input type="hidden" name="courriel_usager" value="<?= $_SESSION[" courriel "] ?>">
</div>
<button name="ajouterBouteilleCellier" id="ajouterBouteilleCellier">AJOUTER LA BOUTEILLE</button>
```

Comment: `erreurAjtBtl` is set to false, then immediately you check to see if it's true, and only then do you run `preventDefault()`. Since false is never true, `preventDefault()` is never fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the variable "erreurAjtBtl" on every click back to false, even if the input fields were validated successfully before. I would suggest to remove that line and set this variable in change-event like this:

```
  element.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
    if (quantiteValideAjt() && date_achatValideAjt() && prixValideAjt())
        erreurAjtBtl = false;
    else
        erreurAjtBtl = true;
  })
```

I've assumed that validation functions return true or false.

Comment: thanks mplungjan, I've corrected. Your answer is also a good approach :-)

Comment: Yes, But you still do not stop submission if the error is true

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
quantiteValideAjt(); 
date_achatValideAjt(); 
prixValideAjt();
```

all return false if errors, and true if valid,  you need to do

```
btnAjtBtlCellier.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  const erreurAjtBtl = !quantiteValideAjt() || !date_achatValideAjt() || !prixValideAjt();
  if (erreurAjtBtl) evt.preventDefault();
})
```